# Alternative method to set up a binary tree?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I tried to find the method to establish the binary tree. Almost all existing methods like the following code：

```
BiTree CreateBiTree(){
    char ch;
    BiTree T;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch=='#')T=NULL;
    else{
        T = (BiTree)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));
        T->data = ch;
        T->lchild = CreateBiTree();
        T->rchild = CreateBiTree();
    }
    return T;
}
```

such method likes PreOrderTraverse, Is there any other method to establish the binary tree？

Comment: `(BiTree)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode))` looks dodgy

Comment: The title is very strange, but I don't know how to fix it (i.e. I don't know what to write).

Comment: @unwind: I've edited it - i *think* that's the intended meaning, but I'm not sure!

Comment: I'm guessing this code looks fishy because `BiTree` is a typedef:ed pointer, which is very bad practice, as it makes the code unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
T = (BiTree)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));
```

should probably be

```
T = malloc(sizeof *T);
```

[Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and use `sizeof`.

Upper-case variable names in C is very rare and quite confusing, and you shouldn't `typedef` away the pointer asterisk in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

- I'm guessing `BiTree` is a pointer hidden behind a typedef? That's very bad practice, because it makes the code unreadable. Change the `BiTree` typedef to be a plain `typedef struct`.
- Avoid using scanf() or any other complex functions from inside a recursive function, recursion is slow enough without it. (Recursive functions in general are bad because they are so ineffective and hard to read, binary trees is about the only valid use for them.)
- Don't cast the return value of malloc.

As for the algorithm itself, you can create a binary tree without recursion, by using a "previous" pointer in every node, pointing upwards in the tree (similar to a double-linked list). Such implementations consume more data memory, because every node must store an additional pointer, but far less stack memory. The concern for stack overflow that comes with recursion is removed. And they execute *much* faster because the recursion function calling overhead is removed.